# Discord.js unique user list who has sent messages in a channel

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to make a list of unique users who has sent a message/messages in a channel.

However, the code below does not work.
Could someone please tell me, what I am doing wrong?

```
if(message.content === '$usermsg')
{
const chan = message.channel;
var channame = chan.name; //Channel name

chan.send('Messages in ' + '[' + channame + ']');
chan.fetchMessages().then(messages => {

  for (let [snowflake] of messages) { 
      chan.send('snowflake: ' + snowflake); 
  }

}).catch(console.error);
return;
}
```

Comment: Found the answer, Its all working fine. Except the fetchmessages can only get max 100 messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(message.content === '$usermsg')
{
const chan = message.channel;
var channame = chan.name; //Channel ID
var arr = [];
chan.send('Messages in ' + '[' + channame + ']');
chan.fetchMessages({limit:100}).then(messages => {

const usermsgs = messages;
chan.send(usermsgs.size);

for (let [snowflake, message] of usermsgs) {
  arr.push(message.author.id + ',' + message.author.username);
}

  var finalarr = Array.from(new Set(arr));

  for(var mem of finalarr){
      chan.send(mem);
  }

}).catch(console.error);
return;
}
```